# Unable to generate qdoc documentations

Tags: qt

By following this guide http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qdoc-guide-conf.html, I made a simple qdoc configuration file.

```
sourcedirs = ../sources

sources.fileextensions = "*.cpp *.qdoc *.mm *.qml"
headers.fileextensions = "*.h *.ch *.h++ *.hh *.hpp *.hxx"

outputdir  =    ./doc/
outputformats = HTML
```

However, the generated documenation folder is empty, except for the index file and a couple of folders.
[image: folder captured]

Can anyone help explain this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. I just figured out that setting sourcedirs is not enough. You need to set up headerdirs as well.

```
headerdirs = ../sources
```

This solves the issue. qdoc searches headers first and then searches for .cpp files for documentations. qdoc does not search for documentations in header files but it will need header files in order to find the source files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use follow command to generate documentation from your project.

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\...\bin\qdoc.exe your.qdocconf
```

But you must execute this command on the root folder at your config file. Because all paths in config file are depends on that folder.

```
sourcedirs = ../sources
```

Or you can pass an absolute path of configure file in qdoc command.

And QDoc does not look for QDoc comments in .h files. So you have to write your document comments in .cpp or .qdoc files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your information is correct but does not solve the problem. I've figured this out myself...