# qdoc does not generate HTML

Tags: qt, documentation, qdoc

Even my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489115/unable-to-generate-qdoc-documentations) one, the answer provided does not solve my issue.

---

I'm trying to generate my first `QDoc` output.
To test it, right now I have only one comment in `main.cpp`:

```
/*!
 * \brief main
 * \param argc
 * \param argv
 * \return
 *
 * bla bla bla
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
```

Here my config file:

```
#include(compat.qdocconf)
#include(fileextensions.qdocconf)
project = MyProject
outputdir   = docs
outputformats = HTML
headerdirs  = .
sourcedirs  = .
exampledirs = .
imagedirs   = ./images
```

**Question #1**: in the [minimum example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/21-1-minimum-qdocconf.html) the `project` field is not present. But without it, running `qdoc myproject.qdocconf` I get:

```
qt.qdoc: "qdoc can't run; no project set in qdocconf file"
```

**Question #2**: with the `project` field set, this is the output:

```
qt.qdoc: Start qdoc for MyProject in dual process mode: generate phase.
qt.qdoc: No include paths passed to qdoc; guessing reasonable include paths
(qdoc) Could not find the module header in include paths for module "MyProject"   (include paths:  QList() )
       Artificial module header built from header dirs in qdocconf file
qt.qdoc: Parse source files for "MyProject"
qt.qdoc: Source files parsed for "MyProject"
qt.qdoc: End qdoc for MyProject in dual process mode: generate phase.
```

I'm not sure how to include paths. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/21-0-qdoc-configuration.html) I cannot find such an `include` command.
It creates the output `docs` directory but it's almost empty: just the `myproject,index` file is there.

What I have to do further to produce the HTML files?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I'm very sorry but I don't find any match in the whole page you linked for `includepaths`

Comment: Just a side note: I think Qt Company forgot about QDoc.